# how to augment sqlalchemy relationship by custom setter and/or getter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I need create relationship with custom getter and setter. 
It would be nice to define setter/getter parameters on relationship declaration
Also I need alter relation getter even if no data are joined (i.e. change None to something more complex)

Here is roughly what I need:

```
class Address(Base):
    #...

    #hybrid attributes? custom class instrumentation? I need call this function even if no rows are joined to user or company
    def getter(self):
         #for each joined row
         return {'address': "%s %s" % (self.cilty, self.country), 'maximum' : some_data['maximum']}
         #if no row joined
         return {'address': None, 'maximum' : some_data['maximum']}

    def setter(self, user):
         if some_data['only_country'] != user.country:
             raise Exception('You can`t live in %s. sorry', (user.country,))
         self.country = user.country

class User(Base):
    #...
    addresses = relationship(Address, some_data = {'maximum': 1, only_country: 'UA'})

class Company(Base):
    #...
    addresses = relationship(Address, some_data = {'maximum': 7, only_country: 'US'})
```

Now i want to use this relationship as follows

```
u = db.query(User).filter_by(id=1).one()
# I need data from getter here
print(u.address)

u = User()
# I need setter called here with references to user and some_data defined in relationship definition
u.address = Address()
```

Comment: Is it a one to one relationship (apparently not, since "for each joined row")? Could you elaborate a bit what exactly you mean by "having getter/setter on relationship"? How would you use such getter/setter?

Comment: 1. table Address can be used in both one to one and one to many relationships (in different models)
2. I have updated post, thanks

Comment: Main idea is that Address object behavior depends on some data, and i want to pass this data from relationship declaration

Comment: Hmm don't know if that's possible, sorry. Have a look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html if you haven't.

Comment: association_proxy is best solution

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use [association_proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)

For provided example solution looks as follows:

```
class AddressAssociation:

    some_data = {}

    def setter(self, AddressObject, value):
        # change AddressObject here depend on value and self.some_data

    def getter(self, AddressObject):
        # return something depend on AddressObject and self.some_data

    def creator(self, value):
        # return Address() depend on value and self.some_data

    def __init__(self, some_data):
        self.some_data = some_data

    def get_proxy(self, target_name):
        return association_proxy(target_name, None,
            creator=self.creator,
            getset_factory=lambda *a, **kwa: self.getter, self.setter)

class User(Base):
    #...
    addresses_relationship = relationship(Address)
    addresses = AddressAssociation({'maximum': 1, 'only_country': 'UA'}).get_proxy('addresses_relationship')

u = User() # AddressAssociation.creator called
u.addresses = something # AddressAssociation.creator called
print(u.addresses) # AddressAssociation.getter called
u.addresses = something_else # AddressAssociation.setter called
```